# hash table copy can't find word using find function

Tags: c++, hashmap, logic, hashtable

I am building a hash table that uses linear probing as its collision resolution method, and I am stuck on one last check. the copied to table can't find a key that should be there, as it was removed from the original hash table prior to the check.

```
template <class TYPE>
LPTable<TYPE>::LPTable(const LPTable<TYPE>& other){


    max_ = other.max_;
    LargerMax = other.LargerMax;
    size_ = other.size_;

    if (other.size_)
    {
            records_ = new Record*[other.LargerMax];


            for (int i = 0; i < other.size_; i++) // chasnged size from larger max
            {

                    if (other.records_[i] != nullptr)
                    {
                            records_[i] = new Record();    //throws exception after this loop

                            records_[i]->key_ = other.records_[i]->key_;
                            records_[i]->data_ = other.records_[i]->data_;
                            records_[i]->isDeleted = other.records_[i]->isDeleted;


                    }
            }
    }
    else
            size_ = 0;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: @Fureeish. Yes, that's why I don't understand. It goes into the for loop in the find function but never finds the key in the copied table

Comment: what **exactly** then does not work as intented? coparison?

Comment: i am unsure as to why, after removing items from the hash table, the hash table copy can't find a word it's looking for

Comment: @ Fureeish  trying to find a key in the copied hashtable after removing records from the first table

Comment: This a far from a minimum complete working example. In the future, please attempt to boil the code down to an example with reproduces the behavior in question **with a driver**

Comment: @apmccartney. I just posted the whole code for readers sake. The exact problem is the find for loop that iterates the copied table. It returns false for a word that should be in there. This happens after removing items from the original table

Comment: This is still not appropriate. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

The `records_` field of the `LPTable` class need not be a pointer to a pointer; a pointer would have sufficed and this is very likely the source of your problem. Moreover, you should **very likely** prefer a vector for this task.

The strange behavior you're seeing is because of a mistake in the copy constructor of the `LPTable`. You're allocating an array of pointers, then iterating through the `other` and copying the pointers.

In other words, you're not copying the `Record` instance to which the pointer refers.

Corresponding pointers in the `records_` array  of the "copied from" and "copied to" LPTable refer to the same instance of the `Record` class. As a result, when you modify an entry in the "copied from" hash table, those changes are reflected in the "copied to" hash table

Comment: @ apmccartney. sorry i tried to minimize the code showing. What i attempted above crashes the program, wouldn't that how u deep copy the variables in the copy ctor? I am stuck on how to do this proper

Comment: @ apmccartney. the copy ctor in pseudo code. sorry.

Comment: Comments are not an appropriate place for example code, but I'll try to walk though the problem. You've declared the `records_` member variable to be a pointer to a pointer of `Records`. In the copy constructor, you call to the offset dereference of the `record_` member variable ( e.g. `records_[i]`) is not a record. Because `records_` is of type `Record**` the return value of this operation is a pointer. This pointer **does not** have memory allocated to it. Before deferencing and assigning to the value referred to by the pointer, you must first allocate memory to it.

Comment: In other words, before dereferencing and accessing the `key` member variable of the entry, you can call `records_[i] = new Record()`.

Comment: All that said, this would be a *very poor performing* implementation of a hash table. You would be better served by making the `records_` an `std::vector<Record>` (or even Record*) and storing elements contiguously.

Comment: I have updated my code above using that suggestion. For some reason after calling     hashtableCopy.find    the program crashes. I am assuming I am missing some sort of check in the copy ctor?

Comment: I can't change from Record**, it has to be a double pointer, not by my choice.

Comment: Can't see your code, can't run your code, can't debug your code

Comment: it might be the default ctor for my class maybe.

Comment: Record() {
     key_ = "";
     data_ = 0;
      isDeleted = false;

    }

Comment: Dude you need to write a MVCE before I can help anymore. Sorry